# Loop through checkbox column and run sql code with dgv data, dependent on check state, VB.NET

Tags: sql, vb.net, loops, button, datagridview

I am currently working in visual studio express 2013 with an sql back end. I have a checkbox column that is manually put in with design view and then the rest of my columns are pulled from an SQL back end database. I am trying to write some code that will be on a button push that will loop through all of my DGV and run an sql code for each of the rows that have the checkbox checked. I have written code that pulled data out of the same row when you click the checkbox in that row, but I need to be able to have checkboxes selected on multiple rows and then push a button for an sql INSERT command. Here is a picture of my form:

[image]

As you can see in this picture, I need an end user to check off which order he wants to push and then click the push button. How can I do this loop statement?

Comment: does `columns are pulled from a ... database` mean the data is bound?  How so DataTable or what?  I'm confused on why you would INSERT for data already in the back end database...

Comment: @Plutonix sorry i waited a day to get back to this, I got busy. The reason I need to run an insert statement is because this table is being pulled from an sql read only source and I need to move the order number and line number into an on-site program for our processes. I will also be added some information to these rows dependent on the checkboxes and textbox in the form. But to answer your question, yes, this data is bound.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a new dataview with expression 'order = true'?

You can then send a batch of SQL commands to your database based on the rows in your new dataview, separated by ;
I'm guessing you are inserting rows into a different table to the one you fetched the data from?

I can write you some code if you're not sure what I mean.

When you create your SQL to send the query to the database, instead of just sending:

```
"INSERT INTO  tablename (order) VALUES (@value)"
```

you can send:
"INSERT INTO  tablename (order) VALUES (@value); INSERT INTO  tablename (order) VALUES (@value2); INSERT INTO  tablename (order) VALUES (@value3)"

Comment: Sorry I took a day to get back to this, I got busy with other parts of work. I'm not entirely sure about a batch command or a dataview. Some code would be helpful.

Comment: that's OK, I'm busy too.

Comment: Dim Myfilter as String = "order = true"
Dim dv As New DataView(CurrentTable, Myfilter, "id ASC", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)
DIm ordertable as new datatable = dv.ToTable

This will create a table with only checked items from your original table (CurrentTable)

Comment: what is that "currenttable," is that my DGV name or something else?

Comment: CurrentTable is the datatable you used to fetch your data from the database. Is datasource of the DGV set to a datatable?